# C# cascading DropDownList getting Undefined

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to creating a cascading dropdownlist base on what is selected in 1st dropdown list but the 2nd list keeps getting Undefined.

Here is the dropdowns from my View:

```
      <td align="left">
            @Html.DropDownList("goals", ViewData["goals"] as SelectList, new { @class = "dropdownSource" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_goal)
       <td align="left">
            @Html.DropDownList("priorities", new SelectList(string.Empty,"Value", "Text") , new { @class = "clsColumnNames" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.budgetList[i].align_to_district_priority)
       </td>
```

Here is my script:

```
<script>
    $("select.dropdownSource").live("change", (function () {
        $("#priorities").empty();

        var columnSelectBox = $(this).parent("td").next("td").find("select.clsColumnNames");

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/PrepareBudget/GetPriorities',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { goals: $(this).find("option:selected").text() },
            success: function (str) {

                $.each(str, function (Value, Text) {
                    $("#priorities").append('<option value ="' + Text.Value + '">' + Text.Text + '</option>');
                    debugger;
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve columns.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }));
</script>
```

And here is my controller:

```
public JsonResult GetPriorities(string goals)
{
    List<string> priorities = new List<string>();

    switch (goals)
    {
        case "Goal 1: Strengthen Early Literacy":
            priorities.Add("Priority 1: Increase access to high-quality PreK classrooms and monitor quality");
            priorities.Add("Priority 2: Attract and retain strong teachers in early grades");
            priorities.Add("Priority 3: Execute a comprehensive District-wide literacy plan");
            priorities.Add("Priority 4: Leverage family and community partners to increase early literacy efforts");
            break;
        case "Goal 2: Improve Post-Secondary Readiness":
            priorities.Add("Priority 1: Improve student engagement through access to rigorous prep courses and personalized learning opportunities");
            break;
        case "Goal 3: Develop Teachers, Leaders, and Central Office to Drive Student Success":
            priorities.Add("Priority 1: Develop leadership pathways for teachers, coaches and school administrators");
            priorities.Add("Priority 2: Create competitive compensation systems to attract and retain classroom and school leaders");
            priorities.Add("Priority 3: Ensure high-quality feedback and evaluation of all staff connected to career development opportunities");
            priorities.Add("Priority 4: Use data deep dives in schools and District offices to drive continuous improvement");
            break;
        case "Goal 4: Expand High-Quality School Options":
            priorities.Add("Priority 1: Implement a common School Performance Framework to communicate school quality");
            priorities.Add("Priority 2: Transition to a student-based funding model");
            priorities.Add("Priority 3: Establish new school models that focus on different career training and specialized learning");
            priorities.Add("Priority 4: Commit to a compact with our charter schools");
            break;
        case "Goal 5: Mobilize Family and Community Partners":
            priorities.Add("Priority 1: Improve how we deliver information to parents through multiple communication avenues");
            priorities.Add("Priority 2: Provide ongoing diversity and customer service training to all staff and hold them accountable for service quality");
            priorities.Add("Priority 3: Establish a volunteer hub to connect partners to the District's student mission");
            break;
    }
    return Json(priorities);
}
```

Why am I getting Undefined for each priority in the priority dropdown?

Comment: please learn to use proper tagging while posting a question

Comment: Please do not edit your question such that it invalidates existing answers. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
//...
success: function (str) {
                $.each(str, function (index, text) {
                    $("#priorities").append('<option value ="' + index + '">' + text + '</option>');
                });
            },
///...
```

Comment: Thank you!  Why does it only work for the first row in the For loop?

Answer (score 0):

Your action method is returning a **list of string**. Each item in the list (a single string object) does not have a `Text` or `Value` property. But your client side code is trying to access those.

You can change your server method to return a list of SelectListItem which has a Text and Value property.

```
public JsonResult GetPriorities(string goals)
{
    List<SelectListItem> priorities = new List<SelectListItem>();
    // to do : Replace the below hard coded items with the real items you want
    priorities.Add(new SelectListItem { Value="Priority 1",
    Text="Priority1: Increase access to high-quality PreK classrooms and monitor quality"});

    return Json(priorities);
}
```

*If you are reading the priorities from a db table, It is a good idea to keep the stringified version of the Id of the record in the `Value` property*

With the above server code change, your current client side code will work.

**Another option** is to update your client side code to use the item (*single string*) in the array as it is.

This should work.

```
success: function (itemsArray) {
$.each(itemsArray, function (index, p) {

   $("#priorities").append('<option value ="' + p+ '">' + p+ '</option>');

});
```

I also noticed another issue in your code. As of jQuery 1.7, jQuery `live` method is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). You should consider using `on` instead of live.

```
$(function(){

  $("select.dropdownSource").on("change", (function () {

  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you!  That works great for the first dropdownlist in my For loop. How do I get it to work for each row in my For loop?

Comment: Which for loop are you talking about ? I do not see any for loops in your question. Also the above code is for the second dropdown !

Comment: Sorry trying to figure out how to update my original question to include the For loop

Comment: Great thank you for the additional suggestion.....very much appreciated.  I finally got my For loop posted in my View in original question.

Comment: Your original question was about the undefined error for which 2 answers were posted. It is not a good idea to update question with a a new issue ( I Actually do not understand what your new problem is!) You need to be very clear when you write a question. Please take a moment to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much for your help. I will ask another question.